# How to calculate distance matrix using outer function in R

Tags: r, matrix, distance

I have some binary vectors I wish to calculate the tanimoto distance between a matrix and a vector. The only way to do this using the `dist` function is to make it a single matrix, which means the result is a 3x3 matrix. I want to calculate the distance between each of the vectors in `x` with the vector `y`. So the result should be a 2x1 vector. Can anyone suggest how this is done please. Please see my code below. Thank you.

```
x=matrix(c(1,0,1,1,0,0),3,2)

y = c(0,1,1)

dist(cbind(x,y),method = "binary", upper = T, diag = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, object `x` of function `dist` has one vector per row, not per column. So, you should have written your code like this:

```
dist(rbind(t(x),y),method = "binary", upper = T, diag = T)
```

In order to answer your question, try this:

```
dist_y <- function(x) dist(rbind(x,y = c(0,1,1)),method = "binary", upper = T, diag = T)
apply(x,2,dist_y)
```

Comment: This works. Thank you. I didnt add that I would like this done for y also being a matrix. Is there a way that this can be done to extend to this case?

Comment: Sure, just use the same function *dist_y* (replacing y, of course) and then use it with `lapply` and `split` like this: lapply(split(t(x),ncol(x)),dist_y)